# How to add another custom position color into triangle css?

Tags: css, reactjs

How to add the green bar inside the triangle just like this photo ?
[image]

I have try to add a triangle css, but I have no idea how to write the green bar into the triangle css.

css file:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 210px 100vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent #1a202c;
}
```

layout code:

```
<div className={styles.triangle} />
```

Comment: Not possible with a `border`. I'd suggest an SVG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for CSS solution, you may be able to play around with multiple triangles here and get the desired results.

Something like this:

```css
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 210px 100vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent #1a202c;
}

.triangle::before {
    position: relative;
    left: -50vw;
    top: -19px;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 105px 50vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent #83e5da;
}


.triangle::after {
    position: relative;
    left: -100vw;
    top: -16px;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 105px 50vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent #1a202c;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">  

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks subodhkalika, it's working. I will try to adjust the number to achieve what I need. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't play with border, consider modern approach easier to adjust

```css
.box {
  /* triangle size */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  /* */
  background: 
   linear-gradient(lightblue /* line color*/ 0 0) no-repeat
    right/40%, /* 40% = line length */
   #000; /* background color */
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  clip-path: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  translate: 30px; /* the line thickness */
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```